# Notation of integral.

Tags: probability-theory, notation

In some probability book I've come across this notation:
$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x d F(x)$, and it's very confusing, when I see other books defining the same concept as:
$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x) dx$

I wonder... what does that kind of notation mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, $f(x)$ would be the probability density function and $F(x)$ would be the cumulative distribution function.  They are related by
$$f(x)=\frac{dF(x)}{dx}\ ,$$
so $dF(x)=f(x)\,dx$ and the two integrals are equivalent.

In practice, to evaluate the first integral you would probably begin by transforming it to the second anyway.

Comment: Yes, I knew $f(x)$. But I hadn't ever seen the notation $dF(x)$ in an integral just like that. It makes sense like that.

Comment: One should also mention that there are cases where $F$ is not differentiable. Sometimes, it is then possible to interpret $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\mathrm{d}F(x)$ as a [Riemann–Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Stieltjes_integral). (A common case would be that $F$ is piecewise differentiable, then the integral can be evaluated by considering the pieces individually.)